# How to change this code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> // for strlen
#include <stdlib.h> // for atoi
#include <sstream>
void expand_combinations(const char *remaining_string, std::ostringstream& i, int remain_depth)
{
    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        std::cout << i.str() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int k=0; k < strlen(remaining_string); ++k)
    {
        std::ostringstream l;
        l << i.str();
        l << remaining_string[k];
        expand_combinations(remaining_string+k+1, l, remain_depth - 1);
    }
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::ostringstream i;
    if(argc<3) return 1;
    expand_combinations(argv[1], i, atoi(argv[2]));
    return 0;
}
```

How can this code be changed so that it doesn't use ostringstream?

Comment: Could you give more info? What do you want to do? Why do you want to remove the ostringstream?

Comment: What are you allowed to use? if you are not allowed to use `ostringstream`?

Comment: Use of ostringstream should be encouraged. The atoi should be replaced by a (std::istringstream(argv[2]) >> an_integer).eof() call. If you are trying to convert this code to C, just provide wrapper so you don't introduce bugs. Also, in C++ exists a library providing a next_combination() function to iterate over combinations

Comment: I just want to remove it because I don't understand it well and I am trying to convert it to objective-c code. This is not homework.

Comment: See you other question. You can use stringstreams in objective-c code. But if you have to port this code, better use a objective-c library providing something similar to next_combination() instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: -1 for poor and nondescriptive title

Comment: Which objective-c library is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is your code with string in place of ostringstream. Normally I'd refactor the code but since your question was pretty specific I'll leave it alone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void expand_combinations(const char *remaining_string, string const & s, int remain_depth)
{
    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int k=0; k < strlen(remaining_string); ++k)
    {
        string str(s);
        str.append(1, remaining_string[k]);
        expand_combinations(remaining_string+k+1, str, remain_depth - 1);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc<3) return 1;
    expand_combinations(argv[1], "", atoi(argv[2]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by refactor the code? Do you already see something that can be optimized?